# Html email not sending using php

Tags: php, android, html, email

I am trying to send email in html format using php file but each time i receive email with this html code instead of html format of text ... if i move header code above message its not sending email so i put it at bottom 
please help ... thank you

```
<?php

  $name = $_POST['name'];

  $to = $_POST['to'];

  $from = $_POST['from'];

  $subject = $_POST['subject'];

  $message = "

  <html>

  <head>

  <body>

   <h1>

   <center>Meeting invitation</center>

  </h1>

 </body>

 </head>

 </html>

   ";

 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

 $headers = "From:" . $from; 


 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

 ?>
```

Comment: Why dont you use phpmailer. This will work without any problems

Comment: first: define $header = ""; and after push string in to $header, like .= .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/2b0v4oub/1/) is working example of mail code in PHP:

```
<?php 

if($_GET["submit"] = "Send" )
{
     $namezz = $_GET["name"];
     $emailzz = $_GET["email"];
     $cityzz = $_GET["city"];
     $phonenozz = $_GET["phoneno"];
     $subj = $_GET["subject"];
     $commentszz = $_GET["msg"];
}

ini_set("SMTP","www.cccccc.in");

// email address to whoon to send 
$email = "ccc@gmail.com"; 

// The subject 
if( $subj == "No-Subject")
{
    $subj =  "New Enquiry form form ". $namezz; 
    $subject = $subj;
}
else
{
    $subject = $subj;
}


// The message 
$msgg = "Name :".$namezz ."\n 
Email :".$emailzz ."\n 
City :".$cityzz ."\n
Phone Number :".$phonenozz ."\n
Subject:".$subj ."\n
Message :".$commentszz;

$headers = "from :".$emailzz;

mail($email, $subject, $msgg, $headers); 

echo 'thanks for sending email';


?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You forget ".", for string

```
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
```

must be

```
 $headers .= "From:" . $from;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add this

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code..

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

  $to = $_POST['to'];

  $from = $_POST['from'];

  $subject = $_POST['subject'];

  $message = "

  <html>

  <head>

  <body>

   <h1>

   <center>Meeting invitation</center>

  </h1>

 </body>

 </head>

 </html>

";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <gaurav@example.com>' . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something along the lines of

```
<?php
$val=mail('your email address', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
?>
<p>Your email has been sent.</p>
```

With the html page containing

```
  <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="subject">
<textarea id="textarea"  rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Entermsg:"></textarea>
```

Using the `mail` function in PHP is simple and straight forward

In your code you'll need to modify

```
$headers .= "From:" . $from;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put a `.` in this piece of code

```
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

So this is your final code

```
$headers .= "From:" . $from;
```

Because the `.` is used to concatenate in PHP.